# Avoiding Junk data into oracle table using sqlldr control file

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

Below is the my raw text file

```
*** REPORT :RUN DATE : 01-NOV-20
TOTALCOUNT

----------

    436203

----------

      4274

*** REPORT :RUN DATE : 02-NOV-20


REPORT 1

ID     ACC     NAME 
    
----- ------ ----

12345 67890  ABCD

12345 67890  ABCD

12345 67890  ABCD

12345 67890  ABCD

12345 67890  ABCD

12345 67890  ABCD

12345 67890  ABCD

-----------------

REPORT 2


ID     ACC     NAME
     
----- ------ ----

12345 67890  ABCD

12345 67890  ABCD

12345 67890  ABCD
```

I know how to import all the records into oracle table using sqlldr control file.

My requirement is I want only meaningful records (below the ID, ACC, NAME) into my table not for the junk row like (-,*,TOTALCOUNT, REPORT1, REPORT2).

How to remove/mention these rows into control file. Below is the control file

load data

infile 'E:\SQLLDR\ATM\EMV\total_atm.txt' "str '\r\n'"

append into details

fields

trailing nullcols(

```
id position(1:5),

acc position(7:11),

name position(13:16)
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Pre-process the file first with a script that saves only the data you want to load.  You could use WHEN clauses, but that would get ugly in the control file and those lines would be reported as errors in the load process, which is not entirely correct and would make checking on the load difficult.